# AZURE Beginner lost with a 503 error - Need help where to start to get site back up.

Tags: azure, umbraco7

I hoping that someone can help us and guide us to where I should be looking in Azure to fix my 503 error. My site has been down for over 24 hours now.

**Steps I have taken since the 503 error:**

- Commented out Redirects in my web.config file for "non-www to www" and "http to https" for the SSL certificate
- In Azure I have un-binded the SSL certificate from www and non-www
- Cleared Cache in my browsers
- Rebooted my routers

My technical experience levels - 
**Azure Level of Experience:** Beginner
**CMS: Umbraco**

Answer (score 0):

Check your Azure and Umbraco logs for any errors or anomalies.

The Umbraco logs are located in App_Data/Logs/